# Hard drive mounting Question Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, mount

Hey I just bought a new server and it's running debian

it has 2 2tb hard drives in it, and I'm looking to mount the second one to a specific folder.

an fdisk -l gives me this

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      243202  1953514583+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x197e197d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1      243200  1953503968+   7  HPFS/NTFS
debian:~#
```

are they both already mounted? Since it looks different than it usually does. And if the second one isn't how can I mount it to a var/www2 folder?

Thanks

Comment: How 'different' is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both questions can be answered by `mount`.

To look where something is mounted, just issue `mount`.

To mount something to something, just do `mount /dev/sdb1 /var/www2`.

But watch out! The /dev/sdb1 is an NTFS file system (not a "native" Linux file system)

Answer (score 1):

`mount` or `df` will show you the filesystems that are mounted.  `fdisk` is just showing that the devices are physically attached (which is of course, a good first step :))

As long as /var/www2 already exists, it should be as simple as `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /var/www2`

There are a couple things that can get in the way here.  If /var/www2 doesn't already exist, you have to create the directory.  If it does exist, you don't want any content in there, because once you mount a filesystem at that location, the original contents won't be accessible any more.

Your filesystem is formatted as NTFS, which typically means you'll need a package for ntfs utlities (ntfs-3g on fedora, don't know about debian).  If this drive is only going to be used on this box, I'd recommend formatting it w/ EXT, because using windows filesystems on linux is going to be a pain as the permissions are completely different.

Additionally, if you want this mount to happen automatically upon reboot, then you should add an entry in your /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `fdisk` tells you nothing about whether or not your disks are mounted. Run `mount` to see what disks are mounted where. Permanent mounts are specified in `/etc/fstab`, which you should be able to figure out based on a short Google search or looking at existing entries.

Your first disk is using GPT. This is an alternative disklabel format which is the better choice for 2 TB+ disks, since MBR is only capable of handling disks up to that size. Unfortunately, `fdisk` is only for MBR disks. You'll need to use a GPT-enabled tool. `gdisk` is very similar to `fdisk`; `apt-get install gdisk` to use it. `parted` is also capable of handling GPT disks; you may use it instead if you prefer.

The second drive's main and only partition is formatted using NTFS. This is not the best choice for a Linux system since NTFS supports few Linux filesystem features and integrates poorly. Ideally, you should reformat it as a Linux filesystem. A common default nowadays is Ext4: run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` to reformat (after making sure the partition is unmounted).